# Combining Herbal Powder Extract

Tags: everyday-chemistry, food-chemistry

If I mixed two powdered herbal extracts together and put them through distillation process, then would I end up with a high concentrated form of the two extracts combined together? I'm trying to make an all natural energy drink. I'm not sure if i should just mix the powdered herbs or use some chemical process to combined the herbs into a concentrated form. I figured I would need high doses of the herbs in order for the drink to have an affect. So, should a chemical process to combined my ingredient, or just use herb tictures to avoid a powdery taste?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could fill in some further information. Are the powders not fully soluble in water? Are they the outcome of a real extraction process, e.g. using solvents other than water, or just obtained from grounding dried plant material? Are the powders soluble in ethanol? If so, can you use water/ethanol mixtures for your drink? Did you consider to use edible surfactants to solubilize the non-polar, water-insoluble compounds?

Comment: I'm sorry, let me clarify. I'm trying make an energy drink. My plan is to create an all natural drink using h

Comment: I'm sorry, let me clarify. I'm trying make an energy drink. My plan is to create an all natural drink using all herbal ingredients. I was looking around and found, for example, pure ginkgo biloba in a leaf extract powder and liquid form. My question was if I purchase an over the counter leaf extract powder to make my drink, can I just mix the extract in water or something, or will I need to do some kind of chemical process to properly mix all the different herbal extracts into one solution? I'm sure the extracts are water soluble.

Answer (score 1):

If this is an energy drink for humans then the active are either soluble in water or ethanol. The standard factory method is to use supercritical CO2 extraction. Check the method for production of instant coffee. Briefly, they mix coffee beans with CO2 at 40C (above critical temperature and under very high pressure. Then they filter it and drop the pressure. Components precipitate out. You can drop it to certain value, filter to second chamber, drop pressure slightly, filter move to third chamber, drop pressure to 1 Atm. In this case second chamber can have a single component. In case of coffee caffeine precipitates in second chamber. Now mix stuff from first and third chamber to get decaf.

Ethanol extraction works ok and is used by pharmacists. It is hard to concentrate it however. And ethanol is an active ingredient on its own.

Water extraction is the dirtiest way mainly because it is difficult to concentrate your material.

Comment: Thank you, I restated my question in case I wasn't clear. I'm sorry, let me clarify. I'm trying make an energy drink. My plan is to create an all natural drink using all herbal ingredients. I was looking around and found, for example, pure ginkgo biloba in a leaf extract powder and liquid form. My question was if I purchase an over the counter leaf extract powder to make my drink, can I just mix the extract in water or something, or will I need to do some kind of chemical process to properly mix all the different herbal extracts into one solution? I'm sure the extracts are water soluble.